# Is it possible to run ECMAScript on Lua?

Tags: javascript, c++, lua

Sorry ,I'm very new with lua , but just would like to know if I can run ECMAScript on Lua ?

I have main application(C/C++) will pass std::string(ECMAScript expression) to lua script to process condition ?
Sorry if my question is not clear enough.

Thank you very much

Comment: lua file is generate on run-time

Comment: Lua is a programming language, js is another programming language; it would be strange if you could. Maybe you need a javascript engine like V8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a Lua module out there somewhere that provides this functionality, but no, the core Lua API does not provide both a Lua parser *and* a JavaScript parser. If you want to pass Lua a string to execute, you pass Lua a *Lua string* to execute.